# EC2 Instance Connect hangs on aws-cli calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam

I'm using terraform to create an EC2 instance and an AWS Lambda function. I'd like the EC2 instance to be able to assign tags to all resources across the account using the `resourcegroupstaggingapi`, e.g `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi tag-resources`. When I run the following command from the AWS CLI via EC2 Instance Connect (after configuring the CLI of course), the command hangs. I suspect this might be an IAM issue. Does the following configuration provide the necessary permissions to achieve my goal?

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2.0"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

data "aws_ami" "amazon_linux_2" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm*"]
  }

  owners = ["amazon"]
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role" {
  name = "ec2_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ec2_policy" {
  name = "ec2_policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.ec2_role.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "tag:GetResources",
        "tag:TagResources",
        "tag:UntagResources",
        "tag:GetTagKeys",
        "tag:GetTagValues"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Action": ["ec2:*"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Action": ["lambda:*"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:PassRole",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ec2_profile" {
  name = "ec2_profile"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.ec2_role.name}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_ssh" {
  name        = "allow_ssh"
  description = "Allow SSH inbound traffic"

  ingress {
    description = "TLS from VPC"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "my_lambda" {
  name = "backend-service"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
    function_name = "lambda"
    role = aws_iam_role.my_lambda.arn
    runtime = "nodejs12.x"
    filename = "index.js.zip"
    handler = "index.handler"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web-ec2" {
    ami = data.aws_ami.amazon_linux_2.id
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id}"]
    iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2_profile.name}"
}
```

Note that the IAM user I am using has the `AdministratorAccess` policy applied to it.

Comment: Your security group doesn't allow any egress traffic so you won't be able to talk to the AWS API from it. Terraform by default removes the egress rule that AWS automatically adds to security groups because it complicates how the API is managed and is also a bit of a surprise for users expecting to fully define their security group rules.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR you were right, that solved it. If you create an answer out of this, I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Just added an answer and realised that there's a duplicate at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025189/2291321 so it's probably better to close it as a duplicate of that instead. If you find that useful then you might want to upvote that answer instead. If you disagree with it being a duplicate I can revert the closure and undelete my answer but I think that answers the issue about egress rules for security groups with Terraform.